# How long does it take to purge a file from the CloudFlare cache globally?

Tags: java, jsp, caching, cdn, cloudflare

For our app, we need to purge a single file that is periodically updated from the CloudFlare cache:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169386-How-do-I-purge-a-single-file-from-cache-

What I am wondering is - how long does this take in practice?  Is there any kind of SLA on this?  Anyone with production experience with CloudFlare cache purging - your thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

We would like to purge it and have it be gone within 5 seconds - do you think this is realistic?

Comment: you will be advised to use api: https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s4.5  5 seconds is realistic, though I wouldn't expect an SLA for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It generally goes out almost immediately for purging items from cache. You still might have issues with browser caching and DNS caching in some cases.